# You should contact AdBlock Plus and convince them to add Stack Exchange to its Acceptable Ads

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

**Important Note:** *This feature request is for **SE Employees** and not for site individuals. Sorry for the confusion.*

From AdBlock Plus:

> ### Allow Acceptable Ads
>
> Since many websites rely on advertising revenue, Adblock Plus's default settings encourage the use of nonintrusive advertising rather than annoying, irrelevant ads.
>
> To accomplish this, we've established a set of strict guidelines known as the Acceptable Ads initiative. Together with our users and
>   third-party contributors, we have defined acceptable ads and outlined
>   appropriate ad placement and size. Ads meeting these criteria are
>   visible. You can, however, disable this feature at any time and browse
>   ad-free.

Stack Exchange's ads aren't intrusive. They are relevant, and have a small size. I actually didn't know Stack Overflow had ads until not too long ago, then I disabled AdBlock Plus on Stack Exchange.

I think, for you guys' own sake, (SE Employees) you should convince AdBlock Plus into adding you to its Acceptable Ads.

Comment: For reference, here is their criteria: https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads#criteria

Comment: I'm lazy.  Can you provide a link so I can do this quickly?

Comment: @ryanyuyu https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads#application has the info and https://eyeo.com/acceptable-ads-application.html is the actual form.

Comment: @BSMP "your site"? "job title"?  Not sure that I should be filling this out on SO's behalf.  Perhaps this is a feature-request for one of the CMs to do this?

Comment: OP, you might want to update your post to make it clearer that an SE employee needs to act on this.

Comment: Uh, I thought it was fairly obvious that this was intended for the staff and not the community, considering it's not the community but the staff that manages the ads in the first place (hence "your site" and "job title" in the application form). And I'm usually *terrible* at reading "you"s correctly.

Comment: ...and then he turned around and said "Folks... this "internet" thing you have going on....enjoy it while it lasts"

Comment: *Uh, I thought it was fairly obvious that this was intended for the staff and not the community* - OK, OP should edit out the clarification then.

Comment: And *this* is why nobody should use AdBlock Plus (who gave away bags filled with advertising at some OSS conference, to add insult to injury)

Comment: @BSMP no, this is toward the staff... I'm not responsible for how the staff whitelist their ads, I'm just coming up with the idea.

Comment: @BoltClock to be fair, at the time this meta post was not tagged with feature-request.  It was discussion, at which point I assumed I could actually help.

Comment: @AbAppletic - I know it's toward the staff. BoltClock and 26 others say I should not have suggested that there be any clarification in the post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Fair enough. I didn't need to look at the tags to determine that this was intended for the staff, but I can see why you would have made that assumption.

Comment: @mirabilos [you can opt-out](https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads#optout) of "acceptable ads" (thank god). It's in the last sentence of the quote in the post.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga it’s more a matter of trust than of what can be opted out

Comment: @mirabilos yeah I just checked the settings for ABP on multiple devices and realized they don't sync... so I've been duped into browsing with "acceptable ads" for quite a while now. So bad.

Answer (score 75):

I say **nay** as this goes against Stack Exchange's policy of [not caring about if you use adblock](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/). If you want to see ads you can turn off your adblocker or whitelist the site. If you don't want to see ads and are suddenly forced to because the company requested this from Adblock then it starts to seem like Stack Exchange does care about if you see their ads.

Comment: Note that you need to *pay* for this too: https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads#revenue *"large entities (those with more than 10 million additional ad impressions per month due to participation in the Acceptable Ads initiative) have to pay. For these entities, our licensing fee normally represents 30 percent of the additional revenue created by whitelisting its acceptable ads."*

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Wow, I never knew that. Even more reason not to do it.

Comment: ABP does let you stop seeing acceptable ads, of course, but I can see your point here.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker excellent reason not to use ABP, and switch to uBlock ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker on the other side, it is 30 percent only on the additional revenue. It means that you still gain 70% of that revenue compared to if you do not register.

Comment: you do know that it's an opt-out, right?  you can go and remove ALL of the acceptable ad whitelists and not see a single ad.  I do this, cause I don't' trust ad networks to not give me viruses.

Comment: Nay, nay and thrice nay © Frankie Howerd

Comment: "and are suddenly forced to" You're not forced to view ads just because ABP deems them acceptable; whitelisting acceptable ads is a feature that can be easily toggled off in settings if desired. Personally, I've left that setting on specifically because I want to support sites which use non-intrusive advertising; even sites which I don't visit frequently enough to have whitelisted.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Stack Exchange **does** care whether you use an ad blocker.  From that same article: "More accurately: we hope that they won’t, but we understand that some people just don’t like ads."  The point of the article is that SE isn't going to force people to view their ads, but people who have configured ABP to show acceptable ads have already opted in to the kind of advertising that SE runs.

Comment: Forget "acceptable ads" - that is pure user deception. most people don't even realize they with `Adblock Plus` running, they will still get ads! They think since its an adblocker, they won't see any ads. I switched to `uBlock Origin` because they dont have any phoney "acceptable ads" nonsense.

Answer (score 6):

**Question about this:**   I looked at the criteria they use for "acceptable" ads and they all seem to be about placement, aesthetics, and intrusiveness.

But one of my big concerns with ads is malware.   It has been repeatedly shown that ads can carry a malware payload and that these payloads can infect a computer without the user needing to click on the ad.   So, to me, ad-blocking is part of my security measures, along with using anti-virus software and similar things.   Does whitelisting subject the ad to checks against malware, and how robust are these?

In my case online advertisers are ripping off the companies whose products or services are being advertised.  Because in 20 years of surfing the web I've never clicked on an ad or responded to one.  This is an easy statement to make because the ads are virtually never about a product or service I'm in the market for.  If the web is gathering information about me, they're certainly not using it to direct relevant ads to me.  So any company that pays an advertiser to advertise to me is getting ripped off.

Comment: I see this "I don't click on ads so I'm worthless to advertisers" sentiment in a lot of places. I can't speak to our specific situation here because I'm not too familiar with our ads system, but speaking generally: some advertising isn't about direct conversions, it's about increasing brand recognition/familiarity for future interactions in different contexts. You don't need to click ads for certain advertisers to care about you -- at least, some times.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I once clicked on a roadside billboard while driving and my car got infected with malware. I tried to set up an ad-blocking system but it made it a bit difficult to merge during rush hour.

Comment: "It has been repeatedly shown that ads can carry a malware payload and that these payloads can infect a computer without the user needing to click on the ad." o.O Sounds like you need to stop using IE6.

Answer (score -7):

I say **yes** as it would show that SE cares about users that care about website revenues while avoiding ads when they are too annoying.

If you already accept non-intrusive ads, you expect to see relevant ads on websites such as SE sites – and maybe you are even interested by those. You should not opt-in again for something you have already opted-in globally.

Comment: If you find yourself on a website where there is a lack of advertisement, and you would like to the advertisements that are currently blocked, you can whitelist the domain yourself.

Comment: +1 Just to add to this, I wholeheartedly agree with AdBlock Plus's decision to whitelist sites which use non-intrusive advertising, and it's one of the reasons I use ABP over other ad blockers like uBlock Origin. I very intentionally left the "Acceptable Ads" whitelist enabled as a way to indicate my desire for those types of ads to not be blocked, and I think it would be perfectly acceptable for Stack Exchange to take advantage of that feature.

Comment: @TinyGiant That only works for websites that I visit frequently, and only if I remember to turn adblock off. Acceptable Ads allows me to support sites which use non-intrusive advertising even if I don't visit them frequently, or in cases where I might forget to disable adblock.